# Is it ok for Vgs be higher than Vds on a n-channel mosfet?

Tags: mosfet

Is is OK to drive the gate voltage of an n-channel MOSFET higher than the drain voltage?

The scenario is turning on a circuit with a sensor that outputs higher voltage than the circuit runs on. Specifically, a 5V sensor and a 3.0V circuit.

The MOSFET I have available is a [2n7000](http://www.fairchildsemi.com/ds/2N/2N7000.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not only is it OK, it's a normal mode of operation for every MOSFET in a switching application.

MOSFETs are typically selected precisely because the drain voltage can be made very low when switched on, usually lower than a BJT. If the drain voltage were higher, and any significant current were being switched, then the MOSFET would get very hot, since power is the product of current and voltage: \$P=IV\$.